# Why does importing pycuda.driver under sudo lead to "libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am trying to import pycuda-2021.1 in a python script. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I have cuda toolkit 11.2 installed and my nvidia driver version is 460.27.04. My python interpretor is Python 3.8. When I execute

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
```

I seem to be able to do so without executing the python script under sudo. However, when using sudo, this leads to the following error:

> ImportError: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: because under `sudo` the paths set by environment variables are not set correctly.  If you actually have a usable install setup, then something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/correct/path/for/cuda python my_script.py` will work.  Or you can set these things for a new `sudo` session which has nothing to do with `cuda` or `pycuda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution myself, by refering to this post: [完美解决ImportError: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://blog.csdn.net/c2250645962/article/details/105671162) (this post is in Chinese). Basically, the solution is to execute the following command:

`sudo ldconfig /path/to/your/cuda/lib64`

which in my case should be

`sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64`